# Ubuntu Server doesn't boot after initial install boot on external hard drive on ASUS G75V

Tags: boot, server, external-hdd

I am trying to install Ubuntu server on a 500gb WD external hard drive. I have an ASUS G75V running Windows 7 off of an SSD with another internal hard drive for storage. I have installed Ubuntu server onto the external hard drive both off a disk and a USB and each time it installs properly, restarts, and boots up normally.

I can do everything on Ubuntu fine but when I shutdown and restart, I cannot boot into the external drive. GRUB2 should be working because during the restart after installation it starts GRUB2 and I select Ubuntu.

If I go into the boot menu I can see my external hard drive but every time I select it it just boots Windows. I have disabled UEFI as well and still nothing. If I put back in the installation USB or disk it does not recognize the external either at the GRUB2 menu and asks if I want to install.

Most solutions online have to do with secure boot which I don't believe I have. Nothing I try boots me back into the new Ubuntu I just installed even though it appears set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by turning off UEFI mode **during installation** of Ubuntu server on the external hard drive. With this disabled I was able to install and then access GRUB2 from the boot menu and boot Ubuntu from there.